# Naive Bayes MultinomialNB ValueError: dimension mismatch

Tags: python, machine-learning

So i am using Naive Bayes MultinomialNB to predict twitter sentiments, i have both train and test data, and i have already trained the model with train data. then i am trying to predict with test data but it says dimension error. How can i solve this?

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
pf = pd.read_csv('/content/train.csv')
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(pf.original_text)
model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(tfidf,pf.sentiment_class)
test_csv = pd.read_csv("/content/test.csv")    
test_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(test_csv['original_text'])

test_tfidf.toarray()

array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.15573603, 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.2400925 , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.46763784,
        0.        ],
       ...,
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.182512  ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.42798355,
        0.        ]])
```

so when i use model to predict, it throws dimension error.

```
model.predict(test_tfidf)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-90-34ca51ed204c> in <module>()
----> 1 model.predict(test_tfidf)

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    518 
    519             if other.shape[0] != self.shape[1]:
--> 520                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
    521 
    522             result = self._mul_multivector(np.asarray(other))

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Comment: Can you check shapes of `tfidf` and `test_tfidf` ?

Comment: @CoMartel I dont know it suddenly started working!!! duh! without any correction..